# fail to extract value using regex

Tags: regex, scala

I have a strig that looks like:`"bla bla bla PersonId:fruhdHH$skdjJIFROfUB3djeggG$tt; bla bla bla"`

and I want to extract the PersonId, so basically I need everything that is between `PersonId:` and the `;`, I did something like:

```
val personIdRegex: Regex = """PersonId:\+s;""".r
val personIdExtracted = personIdRegex.findAllIn(str).matchData.take(1).map(m => m.group(1)).mkString
```

its not working thought, pretty weak in regex would love some help :)

thanks!

Comment: Will there always be only 1 match?

Comment: yes @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Is it a requirement to use a regex? Because this seems to be easily solvable without one to be fair.

Comment: @JohnSmith sorry, edited, it was just a mistake in the question

Comment: In your code snippets you wrote `EntryID` while your example string contains `PersonID`. Is that just a silly mistake, am I right?

Comment: @Ben would love to hear a suggestion :)

Comment: @Viç yes :), edited

Comment: Use [`"""(?<=PersonId:)[^;]+""".r.findFirstIn(str).get`](http://rextester.com/IPXBJB63337). Why use `findAllIn` if there is always one match.

Comment: I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50600834/3832970) with 2 Scala solutions. I think the one with `match` block is actually the best one for you.

Comment: Your code is in Scala, so the Java tag is the one that should be taken out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could update your regex to

[`PersonId:([^;]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/SHLx84/1)

This will capture not a semicolon in the first capturing group `([^;]+)`

Then using your code it would look like:

```
val personIdRegex: Regex = """PersonId:([^;]+)""".r
val str = "bla bla bla PersonId:fruhdHH$skdjJIFROfUB3djeggG$tt; bla bla bla"
val personIdExtracted = personIdRegex.findAllIn(str).matchData.take(1).map(m => m.group(1)).mkString
println(personIdExtracted)
```

That will give you:

```
fruhdHH$skdjJIFROfUB3djeggG$tt
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DCGSK47199)

Answer (score 5):

You can use that regex:

```
String test="bla bla bla PersonId:fruhdHH$skdjJIFROfUB3djeggG$tt; bla bla bla";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("PersonId:([^;]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Search for PersonId: and add the value until the first ; in a group

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the first match (as there will always be one match in the string), it makes more sense to use [`findFirstIn`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#findFirstIn(source:CharSequence):Option[String]):

```
"""(?<=PersonId:)[^;]+""".r.findFirstIn(str).get
```

The `(?<=PersonId:)[^;]+` regex means:

- `(?<=PersonId:)` - assert there is `PersonId:` text immediately to the left of the current position
- `[^;]+` - 1+ chars other than `;`

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/PZD2Yr/1).

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/GNGTPQ):

```
val str = "bla bla bla PersonId:fruhdHH$skdjJIFROfUB3djeggG$tt; bla bla bla"
val personIdRegex = """(?<=PersonId:)[^;]+""".r
val personIdExtracted = personIdRegex.findFirstIn(str).get
println(personIdExtracted)
// => fruhdHH$skdjJIFROfUB3djeggG$tt
```

Or, a more natural way, use `match` block with an unanchored regex (here, you may match optional whitespace  between `PersonId:` and the ID itself without restrictions):

```
val personIdRegex = """PersonId:\s*([^;]+)""".r.unanchored
val personIdExtracted = str match {
  case personIdRegex(person_id) => person_id
  case _ => ""
}
```

See [this Scala demo](https://ideone.com/0inxTd).

Here, the `.unanchored` makes the pattern match partial substrings inside a string, and `([^;]+)` in the regex forms a capturing group that can be referred to by any arbitrary name inside `match` block (I chose `person_id`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture 
**fruhdHH$skdjJIFROfUB3djeggG$tt** 
from **"bla bla bla PersonId:fruhdHH$skdjJIFROfUB3djeggG$tt; bla bla bla"**.

You can use this pattern: **".*PersonId:(.*);"**
This will capture the desired value in group 1.

This patter can be disected in the following manner:

**.*PersonId:** : This is telling to match any pattern uptill "PersonId:"

**(.*);** : This is meant to capture any series of characters in the first group until a ; is encountered

Answer (score 0):

You can use following.

```
String str = "bla bla bla PersonId:fruhdHH$skdjJIFROfUB3djeggG$tt; bla bla bla";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("PersonId:(.*?);");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find()) {
               System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```